# Perfomance queue in async programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

this is more of an algorithm issue. I have an async server written in C++. it's a simple http processing special requests - providing a calculation for a product. The service creates N+1 threads for N cores machine.
when the calculation goes above N, a 503 error is sent to the client. While this is technically correct, I wish to avoid this situation. A bigger machine might be implied, but, the machine is loaded in average by less then 2%, so there is no justification for that. I just want to queue the extra requests for times that the machine is less busy (a second or two is acceptable) I'm using boost for the async operation.

Now here is the issue: If I'll queue the extra request(s) by the N+1 thread, there might be a situation in which the requests will never be picked up (if all N threads just left the queue and the N+1 thread inserts a new request) then this request will linger till the next request to free it. other option is to use the **post()** method. problem here that this will load the N+1 thread in case all N threads are busy. thus rendering the server unavailable.

Simple but bad solution is to increase the number of threads. most of the time it's below the limit, but when it's passes the number of cores, the system scheduler will cap the threads which will hinder performances.

Since every 503 cost money and the last solution will actually work, it's not terrible, but so far, this server is a show case for async programming, so I'm looking for a way to keep it like that.

Any ideas will be welcomed!

Comment: Why not just have a queue and let the worker threads read from it (locked), or wait for a semaphore when it's empty?

Comment: You want to implement load balancer and scheduler. This is not a trivial issue. Why not use one of existing workload managers?

Comment: @lorro this is an async server, this will not work.

Comment: @donald : if you mean 'async' as 'threaded', then I fail to see why it wouldn't work, can you please elaborate..

Comment: @lorro async is **NOT** threaded. these are two different things. in this case, it is both.

Comment: @ donald Rather than screaming at @lorro, perhaps you can explain your use of the term "async".  By "async", are you inferring that the request is sent to the server, the calculation is asynchornously computed, and the result is retrieved by a second request?

Comment: @lorro, David,   didn't mean to scream, didn't know that emphasis constitute as one, I didn't mean to offend and I'm sorry if you did. 
async means that the connections to the server are async. there is a polling mechanism an so you can't wait on a queue.

Comment: @donald : That's ok, no offense taken :). That said, I still don't see why it'll not work, I probably need more info on your current architecture. What I'm proposing is to have a quick-and-dirty listener that does nothing but put the entire request in a mutex-protected queue (then listen for the next); then have N threads (or better 2*N) processing the first element of the queue. You might utilize a semaphore so that threads don't need to sleep with a timer when no request is available. This is how I'd solve it, but how is *your* design different, so we could help?

Comment: I ended up doing something that carries some resemblance, as I was pressed for time. I've created to async queue that behaves similar to what you've described. this is not as good as a single queue, but I'll think of something better... thanks anyhow and again, didn't mean to offend!